# ключевое слово parent в методах типа beforeDelete()

Tags: yii2

есть две таблицы productParams и params. Связь в productParams такая:

```
public function getParam(){
    return $this->hasOne(Params::class,['id' => 'param_id']);
}
```

в productParams есть метод

```
     public function beforeDelete()
{
    if (parent::beforeDelete() && $this->param) {
        // beforeDelete() $seoProp->delete();
        $this->param->delete();
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

"Прочитайте" его, его пожалуйста вслух построчно. Я не понимаю логику вызова `parent::beforeDelete()` в самом методе `beforeDelete()` что конкретно делает эта строчка?

При этом этот метод каким-то образом не позволяет выполниться коду

```
foreach (ProductsParams::find()->all() as $allProdParams){
    if (!$allProdParams->param){
        $allProdParams->delete();
    }
}
```

если закоментировать метод beforeDelete(), то всё удаляется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дочерние методы должны вызывать родительские методы. Это согласно принципам SOLID. В данном случае необходимо вызвать метод родителя, чтобы убедиться, что удаление разрешено родителем. У родителя могут быть свои условия на удаление или появятся в будущем. Это надо учитывать, чтобы избежать проблем в дальнейшей разработке.

В конкретном случает, если удаление разрешено свыше, то делаем свои дела и возвращаем труе.

Но удалять в цикле не самая хорошая идея.